# Prevent Check Mark in SVG Animation From Disappearing

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

I have my CSS animation how I would like it. The full animation is the circle is to loop around, completing its shape. There is a small delay in the check mark being filled in the middle of the circle. This way, both of the shapes complete around the same time.

When the animation finally completes, the check mark then disappears.

I know the reason the check mark is disappearing at the end is because I have the opacity in the CSS set to 0 on the check mark element. I've looked at other techniques and saw this used to have the element still appear after the animation is complete.

Why is it even though the opacity is set to 1 at the end of the animation, the check mark is disappearing? Is there a way to fix this and/or if there's a better way to accomplish what I want?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is the SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="checkmark-group" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
  <title>
    Successful Login
  </title>
  <circle id="circle" cx="64" cy="64" r="59.4"/>
  <path id="checkmark" d="M24.75 62l27.5 27.5 51-51"/>
</svg>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
svg {
  width: 128px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

circle, #checkmark {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  stroke-dasharray: 400;
}

#checkmark {
  animation: checkmark-stroke 3s reverse;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes checkmark-stroke {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% { opacity: 1; }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 400;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

circle {
  animation: circle-stroke 3s;
}

@keyframes circle-stroke {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: -400;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

Here is a link to the code in action via CodePen: https://codepen.io/abrielshipley/pen/QOKBGE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property you are looking for is [animation-fill-mode](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-fill-mode-property). Simply add the keyword `forwards` to the end of both `animation` shorthand properties.

It seems `reverse` and `forwards` do not mix (at least in a way I can understand). You should describe the `checkmark-stroke` animation by exchanging 0% and 100% on the keyframes. Probably you also need to alter the `animation-timing-function`: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rYWvyq

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my response. When I tried adding forwards to the end of both `animation` properties, the check mark still disappeared at the end.

Comment: I didn't see your edited comment but that seems to work :) will be forking the codepen to experiment with it more. Thank you so much!